# Can I dynamically create onClick routines for X num of objects in Android

Tags: java, android, onclick

Here is what I'm trying to dot hard coded.  It doesn't allow me to access the iterator within the onClick function if I stick it in a loop.  Is it possible to do this dynamically?

```
    cardBtns[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    cardBtns[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    cardBtns[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    cardBtns[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    cardBtns[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please use a `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

To be used inside an interface a variable needs to be declared with the `final` keyword. However the iterator can't be final because its value has to change so you have to use a second variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    cardBtns[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setText("Button " + String.valueOf(j));
        }
    });
}
```